# Query Error "invalid identifier"

Tags: php, sql, oracle, search

I'm having issues with my database search form. The page runs fine for the most part, but i get two errors.

Warning: ociexecute() [function.ociexecute]: ORA-00904: *$search_term*: invalid identifier in ****/search_results.php on line 53

Warning: ocifetch() [function.ocifetch]: ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in **/search_results.php on line 70

I have commented the relevant line numbers. If someone could tell me why this is happening, I'd greatly appreciate it :)

Edit: Forgot to mention, the table displays nothing despite entering a search term that should get results

Edit 2: When the query is changed to SELECT * FROM Phones, it works fine. It must be something to do with the query.

```
<?php
    $search_term = $_POST['search_box'];

    /* Set oracle user login and password info */
    $dbuser = "**"; /* your login */
    $dbpass = "**"; /* your oracle access password */
    $db = "**"; 
    $connect = OCILogon($dbuser, $dbpass, $db);

    if (!$connect) {
    echo "An error occurred connecting to the database"; 
    exit; 
    }

    /* build sql statement using form data */
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Phones WHERE Name LIKE ".$search_term;

    /* check the sql statement for errors and if errors report them */
    $stmt = OCIParse($connect, $query);
    echo "SQL: $query<br>";
    if(!$stmt) {
        echo "An error occurred in parsing the sql string.\n"; 
        exit; 
    }
    OCIExecute($stmt); //line 53
    ?>

    <h1 class="green">PHP and Oracle databases</h1>
    <h4>Table: <em>Phones</em></h4>
    <div align="center">
    <table width="850" border="0" bgcolor="#339933" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#006633">
    <td width="75">ID</td>
    <td width="75">Name</td>
    <td width="100">Brand</td>
    <td width="75">Photo</td>
    </tr>

    <?php

    // Display all the values in the retrieved records, one record per row, in a loop
    while(OCIFetch($stmt)) { //line 70
        // Start a row for each record
        echo("<tr valign=top bgcolor=#ccffcc>");
        // Output fields, one per column
        // Drainage value in column one
        $fg1 = OCIResult($stmt,"ID"); //"ID number";
        echo("<td width=75>");
        echo ($fg1);
        echo("</td>");
        // Aspect value in column two
        $fg2 = OCIResult($stmt,"NAME");//"Name of product";
        echo("<td width=75>");
        echo ($fg2);
        echo("</td>");
        // Temperature value in column three
        $fg3 = OCIResult($stmt,"BRAND");//"Brand of product";
        echo("<td width=75>");
        echo ($fg3);
        echo("</td>");
        // Height value in column four
        $fg4 = OCIResult($stmt,"PHOTO");//"Photo file path"; 
        echo("<td width=75>");
        echo ($fg4);
        echo("</td>");

        // End the row 
        echo("</tr>");
    } 
    // Close the connection
    OCILogOff ($connect); 
    ?>
```

Comment: @RBarryYoung I've tried that, it doesn't make a difference

Comment: The first error message I wrote in the description, it says "$search_term" instead of $search_term. Something that should be noted, when the query is changed to SELECT * FROM Phones, it works fine. It must be something to do with the query.

Comment: @RBarryYoung the line is `$query = "SELECT * FROM Phones WHERE Name LIKE "."$search_term";` and the error message looks like this Warning: ociexecute() [function.ociexecute]: ORA-00904: "$search_term": invalid identifier in **/search_results.php on line 53

Comment: i've changed the query to `$query = "SELECT * FROM Phones WHERE CONTAINS(Name, '$search_term')";` and im still getting errors. This is truly a mystery @RBarryYoung

Comment: Warning: ociexecute() [function.ociexecute]: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator in **/search_results.php on line 53. The second error is the same @RBarryYoung

Comment: it worked! thank you so much! now all i need to do is make the search case insensitive and im done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your SQL command needs quotes around your `$search_term` contents.

I don't know PHP, but I imagine it should be something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Phones WHERE Name LIKE '%".$search_term."%'";
```

Note the addition of the apostrophes (SQL's quote character) and the percent sign (LIKE's wildcard character). I am not sure how you properly quote apostrophes(') and percent signs (%) in PHP, so you should check on that.

(Sorry, I do not know how to make it into a case-insensitive search on Oracle, you should post that as a separate question.)